# Web page being displayed as plain text instead of html

Tags: html, netlify, vuepress

I have a Vuepress site, deployed with Netlify. If I navigate to "mydomain.com" from the URL bar, it renders fine.

However, if I navigate to a different page from the URL bar, such as "mydomain.com/about", it displays the page's source code as plain text. This only happens in production.

### What I've tried

I tried setting Netlify redirects, as Netlify suggests for SPAs, but that didn't work.

I tried setting the `Content-Type: text/html` header for `/*` routes, according to [Netlify's instructions](https://www.netlify.com/docs/headers-and-basic-auth). The page then rendered as html, but the CSS doesn't get rendered.

This leads me to believe the headers may not be the cause of the original issue.

In Vuepress, I am using [vuepress-plugin-clean-urls](https://vuepress.github.io/en/plugins/clean-urls/) along with the "Clean Urls" setting in Netlify.

### Build folder

I did notice that in the build folder, the only HTML file is *index.html*, while my other pages are just "file", with no extension

### Source folder

My source folder has a *readme.md* file, as per the Vuepress requirements for the index page, and the *about.md* file exists alongside it.

Answer (score 1):

You solved the problem your self. You have to make the files HTML files

Comment: But the CSS isn't rendered so it just seems like there's something else..

Comment: @slanden Try removing the `Content-Type: text/html` now that they are HTML files. Also, make sure you properly imported the CSS

Comment: They're not html, they're files with no extension and the `Content-Type: text/html` was just rendering them as html. I wonder if the file is rendered later than it would if it was an html from the start and that maybe the CSS, although fetched, is not loaded because that "cycle" has passed. Although, maybe not because reloading the page doesn't resolve the issue.